# How can I force urllib2 to time out?

Tags: python, urllib2

I want to to test my application's handling of timeouts when grabbing data via urllib2, and I want to have some way to force the request to timeout.

Short of finding a very very slow internet connection, what method can I use?

I seem to remember an interesting application/suite for simulating these sorts of things. Maybe someone knows the link?

Comment: here's a [code example of `slow_http_server.py`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32685765/4279)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I usually use netcat to listen on port 80 of my local machine:

```
nc -l 80
```

Then I use http://localhost/ as the request URL in my application.  Netcat will answer at the http port but won't ever give a response, so the request is guaranteed to time out provided that you have specified a timeout in your `urllib2.urlopen()` call or by calling `socket.setdefaulttimeout()`.

Comment: very nice. never thought of that!

Comment: I had to use: nc -l -p 80   Great idea though! Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, older versions of netcat have slightly different command line options, IIRC. Glad it worked!

Answer (score 6):

You could set the default timeout as shown above, but you could use a mix of both since Python 2.6 in there is a timeout option in the urlopen method:

```
import urllib2
import socket

try:
    response = urllib2.urlopen("http://google.com", None, 2.5)
except URLError, e:
    print "Oops, timed out?"
except socket.timeout:
    print "Timed out!"
```

The default timeout for urllib2 is infinite, and importing socket ensures you that you'll catch the timeout as socket.timeout exception

Answer (score 3):

```
import socket 

socket.setdefaulttimeout(2) # set time out to 2 second.
```

If you want to set the timeout for each request you can use the timeout argument for [urlopen](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen)

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is the timeout argument for urlopen was only added in Python 2.6

Answer (score 0):

why not write a very simple CGI script in bash that just sleeps for the required timeout period?

Answer (score 0):

If you're running on a Mac, [speedlimit](http://mschrag.github.com/) is very cool.

There's also [dummynet](http://info.iet.unipi.it/~luigi/dummynet/). It's a lot more hardcore, but it also lets you do some vastly more interesting things. Here's a [pre-configured VM image](http://codefromthe70s.org/dummynet.aspx).

If you're running on a Linux box already, there's [netem](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/netem).

I believe I've heard of a Windows-based tool called TrafficShaper, but that one I haven't verified.